# Handle deselected values from Facebook via PassportJS

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am using PassportJS and it's Facebook-Strategy to authenticate users for my site.

All is well when the user doesn't deselect anything in the Facebook pop-up.

However, say the user deselects E-mail, I won't be getting that back, which is obviously in the user's control.

My question is - how do I direct them to "somewhere else" based on the data I retried?

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
clientID: config.facebook.appID,
clientSecret: config.facebook.appSecret,
callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL,
profileFields: ['displayName', 'picture.type(large)', 'emails', 'birthday', 'location']},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){

    var newUser = new userModel({
        fullname    :   profile.displayName,
        profilePic  :   profile.photos[0].value || '',
        email       :   profile.emails[0].value || '',
        birthday    :   profile._json.birthday || '',
        location    :   profile._json.location.name || '',
    });

    newUser.save(function(err){
        done(null, newUser);
    });
);
}
```

I can, of course, do some sort of a preprocessor but I don't know what I need to do if the data is not valid. For instance, say "E-mail" is a must. How will I tell the user: "As you haven't provided the mandatory E-mail field, please fill it in" and then I take the user to a Profile Settings page.

My callback URL on the Facebook app is:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback
```

And it's NodeJS route below:

```
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    successRedirect:'/wall',
    failureRedirect:'/login'
}));
```

Any input will help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think here the user wont deselect the email field. Facebook will provide you all the user data you requested. But if the user email provided in the facebook is not verified then you wont get that information
 `email:profile.emails[0].value` here i.e., the email field will be empty. If you think that the email is mandatory for you then after every successful login just write the code to check whether the email field is empty/null or not. If it is empty then you create a form where you can ask the user to just enter their email.
 I used mongodb and the passport code will be like this,

```
var User = require('../models/user');
    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
        profileFields: ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name'],
      },
      function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
          User.findOne({ 'facebook.id': profile.id }, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
              return done(err);
            if (user) {
              return done(null, user);
            } else {
              var newUser = new User();
              newUser.facebook.id = profile.id;
              newUser.facebook.token = token;
              newUser.facebook.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
              if(profile.emails !=null)
    {
              newUser.facebook.email = (profile.emails[0].value || '').toLowerCase();
    }
    else
    {
    //write your code here to use the form and request the email from the user and then add that email to your database.
    }
              newUser.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                  console.log(err);
                return done(null, newUser);
              });
            }
          });
        });
      }));
```

Now, you don't need to change the nodejs route of success redirect and failure redirect.

Comment: Exactly. My question is - how do I "redirect" the user to that certain page with the form? I only see successRedirect and failureRedirect. Thanks

Comment: Hi mate. I think I may not have been clear. What I am seeing above is how to check if the variables are provided or not. I don't see how the redirect is going to work. I have been doing data validation all over the site but what I don't know is how I can route the user to certain pages based on the data provided. I hope I am being clear now. Thanks